# React native listview rowhaschanged

Tags: listview, react-native

i 'm learning listview of react native, but i keep wonder what is the purpose of rowhaschanged like why we have to use it, when it will be called. I have read many document about it also the same questions on stackoverflow then i tried to catch rowhaschanged by updating a listview to understand it better but it wasn't be called. Can somebody give me exact answers for above questions and help me call rowhaschaned please. Thank for your help

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  constructor (props)
  {
    console.log ();
     super(props);
     /*
     this.ds = new ListView.DataSource ({rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => {
      console.log ('Row Has Changed was called');
      return r1 !== r2} });
      */
     this.state = {
       source :  new ListView.DataSource ({rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => {
        console.log ('Row Has Changed was called');
        return r1 !== r2} })
     };
  }
  hitMe ()
  {
    console.log ('hit me');
    this.setState ({
      source: this.state.source.cloneWithRows([
        {name: 'Tu', age: 4},
        {name: 'Hau', age : 5},
        {name: 'Nguyen', age: 7},
        {name: 'Duy', age: 7}
      ])
    });
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <View style = { {padding: 10} }>
        <ListView
         dataSource = {
          this.state.source
         }
         renderRow = { (data) => <Text> {data.name} is {data.age} </Text> } 
        />
        <Button onPress = {this.hitMe.bind(this)} title  = 'Click me' />


      </View>




    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native will use that comparison to determine if it needs to re render the item of the list or if it is safe to keep re using the same view to avoid wasting resources. Basically is a performance feature.

In your example I don't think it will be called again because the row is not changing so you are not needed to re render the ListView.

You can see more info here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html

By the way, you are using old API. ListView is deprecated and will be removed at some point. You should be using FlatList.

Comment: thank you a lot, it took time for me to understand it